# React HOC simple use-case.. Function NOT returning valid ReactElement (React.isValidElement(H)) === false

Tags: reactjs

The following is a simple index.jsx.
At the bottom, in Workspace's render() method, {C} renders.

In Workspace's render method, C, the child component is rendering, the wrapper is not.  The console.log indicates...
React.isValidElement(W) => returning FALSE.
What am I missing in function wrappedHOC(WrappedComponent) - that it is failing to return a valid React Element?
I have stripped all functionality, save passing the SAME props as the WrappedComponent had.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Kid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <span>{`I, ${this.props.name}, ${this.props.power}`}</span><br/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function wrapperHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
}

class Workspace extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let C = <Kid name={'Wonder Woman'} power={'kill baddies'} />
    let W = wrapperHOC(C);
    if (React.isValidElement(C)) { // is TRUE
      console.log("Child is valid React Component");
    }
    if (React.isValidElement(W)) { // is FALSE
      console.log("Wrapper is also valid React Component");
    } else {
      console.log("Wrapper is NOT valid React Component");
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <span> {C} </span> 
        <hr/>
        <span> {W} </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Workspace />, document.querySelector("#container"));
```

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W is not a valid React Element.

What is a valid React element is `<W />`.

You can check it by changing `React.isValidElement(W)` to `React.isValidElement(<W />)`.

Also, I believe you shouldn't be creating HOC on your render method.

Comment: Thank you.  It was a larger program, whittled it down to bare minimum to retain just the question and added all into a single file for easy read-through here..  No, the HOC creation is not in render() in the code.